# Update SendBird User Profile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sendbird

I want to update user profile of SendBird, for that i am calling

**PUT** `https://{region_identifier}.sendbird.com/v3/users/{user_id}`  url

and passing request Body  as

```
{
  "nickname": "Johnster",
  "profile_url":"https://sendbird.com/main/img/profiles/profile_02_512px.png",
  "issue_access_token": true             
}
```

Here **profile_url** is of string type, But if anyone choose image from gallery or capture by camera in that case we get **bitmap** data, i am converting bitmap into `Base64String` but is not accepted by api.

> How i can pass image taken by camera or gallery as string type?

Comment: can I take a look at your model and your code where you put your Base64 into your model object

Comment: Check out this tutorial: 
[link](https://stacktips.com/tutorials/xamarin/upload-bitmap-image-to-server-using-http-multipart-in-xamarin-android)